# Testing not working CakePHP2.0

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I have created the a test for a controller using Cake `bake` command.

Now, I want to test the function "index" of the controller and for it I do this:

```
public function testIndex() {

   echo "printed";

   $result = $this->testAction("/comments/1");

   echo "not printed";

}
```

1 is the param, the id of the post where the comment is. Anyway, the controller works perfectly well, there's no problem with it.

As you can see, the test crashes after calling the testAction method. (it doesn't print the second echo)

I have seen that if the action called on the controller has any call to its model, testAction call won't work. But, if the action to test doesn't have any call to any Model, then, it works perfectly.

Whats happening here?
By the way, both databases, default and test has data in it so it's not either a problem with the database.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
here you have the rest of the testController generated by Cake bake command:

```
<?php
/* Comments Test cases generated on: 2012-04-12 11:49:17 : 1334224157*/
App::uses('CommentsController', 'Controller');

/**
 * TestCommentsController *
 */
class TestCommentsController extends CommentsController {
/**
 * Auto render
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
    public $autoRender = false;

/**
 * Redirect action
 *
 * @param mixed $url
 * @param mixed $status
 * @param boolean $exit
 * @return void
 */
    public function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true) {
        $this->redirectUrl = $url;
    }
}

/**
 * CommentsController Test Case
 *
 */
class CommentsControllerTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
/**
 * Fixtures
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $fixtures = array('app.comment');

/**
 * setUp method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->Comments = new TestCommentsController();
        $this->Comments->constructClasses();

    }

/**
 * tearDown method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->Comments);


        parent::tearDown();
    }
```

Comment: where is your testAction() method? code?

Comment: It would be good to see the rest of the test case (i.e., the parent class, mocks, imports, etc.).

Comment: I have no idea, its a method defined in CakePHP to work with Tests. It should work: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers

Comment: @jeremyharris i have updated it right now. It was totally generated by cake bake command.

Comment: As specified in the doc, your test case needs to extend `ControllerTestCase` not `CakeTestCase`. This is so it can take advantage of the new `testAction` method.

Comment: Which one should extend ControllerTestCas:  TestCommentsController or CommentsControllerTestCase.
And if so, why then cake bake does it wrong? I didn't touch any code...

Comment: Ok, thanks @jeremyharris i changed it on CommentsControllerTestCase and it works well. Anyway, i dont know why the cake bake command doesn't do it well.

Comment: The bake template doesn't check if it's a controller or not when it adds the test case class. A contribution is welcome, I'm sure :) Also I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're testing controllers, make sure to extend the test case class by `ControllerTestCase` to take advantage of the `testAction()` method.